# Geometry problem. Parallel lines.

Tags: geometry

Three lines, parallel to the sides of a triangle intersect in one point, and the segments of these three lines that are inside the triangle all have lengths equal to x. Evaluate x if the sides of the triangle are a,b,c. I've tried some stuff like similarity.  *How do I solve this?*

Comment: "I've tried some stuff like similarity"...and?

Comment: Not much. I'm not sure how to relate a,b,c to x.

Comment: Are you saying that the segments of the lines inside the triangle all have *length* equal to $x$? I think that ordinarily, a line or segment can’t be equal to a number.

Comment: yeah, exactly. i'll change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the three segments intersect in $P$, we have, by similarity:
$$ d(P,BC) = h_A\left(1-\frac{x}{a}\right)\tag{1}$$
where $h_A=d(A,BC)$ and $a=BC$. Since:
$$ 2\Delta = \sum_{cyc} a\cdot d(P,BC)\tag{2} $$
it follows that:
$$ 2\Delta = \sum_{cyc}ah_a - x\sum_{cyc}h_a\tag{3}$$
so:
$$ x = \frac{4\Delta}{\sum_{cyc}h_a} = \frac{4\Delta}{\sum_{cyc}\frac{2\Delta}{a}}=\color{red}{\frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}}.$$

Comment: Nice. What is Δ, btw? and similarity of which triangles?

Comment: Now I get that delta means the area of a triangle. But why (1)?

Comment: this is so cool..